# Proper project structure for react + hardhat + typechain

Tags: hardhat

After a day of trying to get the combination of react and hardhat to live in the same project I gave up. conflicting tsConfig and a bunch of other issues

So finally decided to keep them as a separate projects (2 root directories one for react, another for hardhat). But now I realized react does not allow importing files outside of the `src` directory.

So what's the proper project setup?

Answer (score 5):

Separating the codebases into projects is what I see most of the time. Some folks will separate them across repositories and then use NPM dependencies to bridge the projects.

Personally, I find the monorepo structure to be a lot more useful here. NPM or Yarn [workspaces](https://yarnpkg.com/features/workspaces) and workspace dependencies would be a good friend!

Using the encapsulation that a monorepo provides, you can isolate your incompatible toolchains.

NounsDAO's [monorepo](https://github.com/nounsDAO/nouns-monorepo) is a great example of this being done on a decently large scale.

---

The premise is pretty simple and follows typical monorepo structure:

1. use workspaces to break up your codebase by tech stack (e.g. separate your contracts from your web interface code)
2. use workspace imports to get cross-workspace imports working (so you won't have the issue with React complaining about unresolved imports, you'd just be importing another package)
3. install whatever specialized tooling you want to in each workspace, the isolation will prevent any incompatibilities or weird interactions between the different toolchains

We can use NounsDAO's [monorepo](https://github.com/nounsDAO/nouns-monorepo) as a case-study here, this is a high-level view of their monorepo structure:

```
.
├── packages/
│   ├── nouns-api/ (Express API server)
│   │   ├── src/
│   │   ├── package.json
│   │   ├── tsconfig.json
│   │   ├── docker-compose.yaml
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── nouns-contracts/ (Solidity contracts, Hardhat + Typechain)
│   │   ├── contracts/
│   │   ├── src/ (
│   │   ├── typechain/
│   │   ├── package.json
│   │   ├── tsconfig.json
│   │   ├── .solcover.js
│   │   ├── hardhat.config.js
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── nouns-webapp/ (React webapp)
│   │   ├── public/
│   │   ├── src/ 
│   │   ├── package.json
│   │   └── ...
│   └── ...
├── .eslintrc.js
├── .prettierrc
├── package.json
└── ...
```

In the root directory, they have all common tooling like ESLint, Prettier, and base Typescript configuration.

In each workspace package, they have completely separate (and sometimes incompatible) toolchains. If we dig into their `package.json` files, we see names like `@nouns/...` and dependencies following that pattern. Typical monorepo stuff!

I could go on about monorepos, but I probably won't say anything that isn't already out there on some blog. It's a useful tool in this case specifically to help you isolate incompatible toolchains!